# Angular 4, custom ErrorHandler doesn't recognize custom Error

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I tried to create a custom global [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html) and followed the instruction detailed [here](https://dpopescu.me/2016/10/21/catching-global-errors-in-angular-2/)

**application-error-handler** (just the important parts)

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        super(false);
    }

    handleError(error: any): void {

        if (error instanceof ApplicationError || error.originalError instanceof ApplicationError) {
            this.addError(error.originalError);
        }
        else {
            super.handleError(error);
        }
    }
```

**app-module**

```
 providers: [
    {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: ApplicationErrorHandler
    }
],
```

**app.component** (only the important part)

```
public ngOnInit(): void { 
    const error = new ApplicationError();
    error.message = "fehler";
    throw error;
}
```

**application-error**

```
export class ApplicationError implements Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    httpStatus?: number = 404;
    applicationStatus?: number;
    errorMessageTranslationkey: string;
    handled: boolean = false;
}
```

in my app.component I throw an ApplicationError (in ngOnInit), my ErrorHandler gets called successfully.
But my error in `handleError` is always of type `Error` and `error.originalError` is always `undefined` no matter if I throw my custom error and there the `if` will never resolve to true.

I have no idea why and how this happens.
What I see is that the error gets, so I assume, wrapped because when I debug I see `error: Error: [object: Object] at viewWrappedDebugError (vendor.bundle.js)`

Any idea what might cause this issue and how I can resolve it?

**EDIT**
As suspected it has something to do with Debugmode. As soon as I enable prodmode with `enableProdMode();` it works as expected.

Still this doesn't really answer my question yet.

**How can I handle my custom error in angular's debug mode?**

Comment: Can you add the block of code where you are throwing the error - with `throw new ApplicationError()`? Also note that `@NgModule()` `providers` property need to be an array like in [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModule-interface.html) definition.

Comment: I added the code where I'm throwing the error.
the thing with `provider` was a typo. I updated the code

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You encounter this problem because `ApplicationError` is not an `Error`.

You can use the following code in order to create a custom error:

```
export class ApplicationError extends Error {

  httpStatus?: number = 404;
  applicationStatus?: number;
  errorMessageTranslationkey: string;
  handled: boolean = false;

  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(message);
    this.name = ApplicationError.name;
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ApplicationError.prototype);
  }
}
```

Related to the topic of creating a custom error, check also these links in order to have a full idea on the subject:

- [extending Error, Array, Map in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work) referenced [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12790)
- [Error - Custom Error Types section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

**Why this needs to be an instance of Error?**
Because your error pass through the following method:

```
function viewWrappedDebugError(err, context) {
    if (!(err instanceof Error)) {
        // errors that are not Error instances don't have a stack,
        // so it is ok to wrap them into a new Error object...
        err = new Error(err.toString());
    }
    _addDebugContext(err, context);
    return err;
}
```

Code available at [`errors.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.3/packages/core/src/view/errors.ts).

Therefore if you are not throwing an `Error` instance, then a new instance is created.

**Intercepting uncatched promises in ErrorHandler**

Another error case is when you return a promise which becomes rejected, from your method that is called by the Angular lifecycle (eg: handler, lifecycle-hook).

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new ApplicationError()));
  }
}
```

Therefore the error handling code can look like:

```
import {ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector} from "@angular/core";
import {ApplicationError} from "./ApplicationError";

@Injectable()
export class ApplicationErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  private errors: ApplicationError[] = [];

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    super(false);
  }

  handleError(error: any): void {

    if (error instanceof ApplicationError) {
      this.addError(error);
    }
    else {
      if(error.rejection instanceof ApplicationError) {
        this.addError(error.rejection);
      }
      else {
        super.handleError(error);
      }
    }
  }

  addError(error: ApplicationError) {
    this.errors.push(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. I was able to fix it

Comment: i need to do same thing except that i need to send mail, can you provide me plunker ?

Comment: and it gets called twice/multiple times, it should load only once.